# Rails json response including nested reources and their methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Hello i"m trying desperately to render json that includes methods within my included nested resources. I tried many variants but just can't get that thing to run.

This is what i have:

```
   format.json {render json: @user, :include => [ :votes, :petitions, :roles ] }
```

And that is what i had hoped to work

```
   format.json {render json:  @user, :include => {  
                       :votes => { :methods => [ :status, :count_users_voted ] }, 
                       :petitions => { :methods => [:status, :count_users_voted] }, 
                       :roles 
                       }
               }
```

Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this to your User model:

```
  def as_json(options = { })
    super((options || { }).merge({
      :methods => [:agrees, :disagrees]
    }))
  end

  def agrees
    self.liked_by_count
  end

  def disagrees
    self.disliked_by_count
  end
```

Pretty straight forward, I hope this helps

Comment: oh thanks a lot i can imagine how that might work. would you be so kind to elaborate? in which of my models would that go?

Comment: It would go in the User model